# Heroku: Testing IronMQ Messaging With Worker Locally Using Foreman

Tags: heroku, worker, foreman, ironmq

I am new to Heroku and I am trying to bootstrap a local development environment. Using Foreman, or another tool, can someone please point me to docs that illustrate sending and consuming a message with a worker. Key being setting up the MQ and the worker consuming the message configured locally. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronMQ (and IronWorker) are both cloud services and currently do not have local install capability. It's fairly easy to interact with the API from your local machine though including pushing messages, getting them, etc.

If you plan on using Push Queues, do keep in mind that in order to "push" back to your localhost you'll need to setup something like localtunner or ngrok. Here is some information on that: http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/#testing_on_localhost

Please feel free to hit us at support@iron.io or live chat: get.iron.io/chat

Chad

Comment: Is this answer still true? I saw an on premise installation described here: http://dev.iron.io/mq/3/on-premise/installation/